# Existence of maximal groupoids and Zorn's Lemma

Tags: category-theory

> Any category $C$ contains a "maximal groupoid", the subcategory containing all of the objects and only those morphisms that are isomorphisms.

The above is a definition, and I believe that this assumes Zorn's lemma, but I'm wondering if it is provable independent of ZL.

Answer (score 6):

Zorn's lemma is not used at all: the second half of the sentence is an explicit definition of the maximal groupoid.  It's the subcategory whose objects are all the objects in the category and whose morphisms are all the isomorphisms in the category.  Zorn's lemma is used to prove the existence of a maximal element in certain posets; it is *not* used to prove that a specific element is maximal, which is what you would be doing here.

Comment: So it's a bit unnecessary to assume a sort of ordering where one subcategory is (partially ordered) greater than a another if it contains fewer morphisms?  I could definitely be misunderstanding.

But this was an exercise, and the point was to show this is always true.  So it doesn't seem entirely obvious to me.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking.  The part where it says "the subcategory containing all of the objects and only those morphisms that are isomorphisms" is the _definition_ of the "maximal groupoid" in $C$.  It is in fact maximal with respect to a certain partial order but that's not particularly important in most contexts.  Perhaps the exercise is asking you to prove that this definition does define the unique subgroupoid of $C$ that is maximal with respect to this order, but it's impossible to say without more context.

Comment: I don't have a problem with the definition.... I perfectly understand that.

My issue is proving that such a subcategory always exists.  I don't see how to prove its existence without using Zorn's lemma..... that's my point.

Comment: You don't need to prove it exists...you have a definition of it.  I guess maybe you want to prove that the definition actually makes sense and defines a groupoid.

Comment: I assume the existence follows from Zorn's lemma....  The book had the statement as a lemma and the proof as an exercise.

Comment: http://www.math.jhu.edu/%7Eeriehl/context.pdf

Page 8.  Is where the problem is listed....  It does want me to prove it exists.

Comment: Literally all it asks you to prove is that the collection of isomorphisms forms a subcategory.  The phrase "the maximal groupoid inside $C$" following that is just a definition.  In other words, it's is just a terse way of saying "Show that the collection of isomorphisms in C
defines a subcategory.  This subcategory is called the maximal groupoid inside C."

Comment: And it is maximal in the sense that it contains any groupoid in $C$, but the point is that you don't need Zorn's lemma to show this, you can just prove it directly. Similarly, any set $X$ is the maximal subset of itself in the sense that it contains every other subset, and you don't need Zorn's lemma to prove this either.

Comment: I really don't have a problem with the phrase "the maximal.... ". Yes, I agree that it is a definition.  The exercise isn't this.  Showing that this is a category is trivial.  The exercise is "[Prove] Any category C contains a "maximal  groupoid "

Yes, I inserted the word "Prove" but do you really think they want us to prove that the maximal groupoid is a (sub)category...  that's really easy.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you.  That answers my question.

Comment: @Squirtle If I wrote "Any category C contains a 'maximal groupoid', the subcategory containing all of the objects and only the identities," then this would probably be a bad name, but I can define my terms however I want. All that needs to be checked is that it does define a subcategory of C, otherwise the definition is inconsistent. Presumably I would make a case that this naming is good via additional theorems. There is no proof obligation that the above definition gives rise to a category that is "maximal" in some sense or is even a groupoid just because I used those words in the name.